# jQuery dialog form submission not POSTing values

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple form like this :

```
<form method="post" name="change_pass" id="change_pass" action="change_pass2.php">
    <input type="hidden" id="uid" value="<?php echo $userid ?>">
    <div id="dialog" style="display:none">
        <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass">Password :
        <input type="text" name="conf_pass" id="conf_pass">Confirm Password:
    </div>
</form>
<div id="weak" style="display:none" title="Weak password">
    <p >Please make sure your password is atleast 8 characters</p>
</div>
<div id="mismatch" style="display:none" title="Failure">
    <p>Password mismatch</p>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I am using jquery ui's dialog function to create a dialogue form like this,

```
$(function(){
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        title : 'You must change your password',
        modal : true,
        closeOnEscape: false,
        dialogClass: 'no-close',
        resizable: false,
        draggable: false,
        buttons: {
            'Change Password' : function() {
                if ( $('#pass').val().length <  8 || $('#pass').val() == 'dantours')  {                         
                    $('#weak').dialog();
                }
                else if ( $('#pass').val() != $('#conf_pass').val()){
                    $('#mismatch').dialog();
                }
                else 
                    $('#change_pass').submit();
                }
        }
    }); 
});
```

But on the change_pass2.php page, the $_POST array is empty. I've been bagging my head against the monitor trying to figure this out.

Comment: I notice your hidden input has no `name` attribute, and therefore won't be in the post, though the others do.

Comment: Personally, I think it's a really bad idea to hide the username but ask for a password. What would be the reason for doing that?

Comment: Try and use Chrome Developer Tools (integrated with Chrome) or Firebug to see what actually gets submitted from your form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery dialog will move the dialog to the end of the body, which is outside the form scope, as stated [here](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/dialog-widget-forms-append-to-forms-when-applicable). So there won't be any data posted.

You need to do this:

```
$("#dialog").dialog({your options...}).parent().appendTo($("#change_pass"));
```

Comment: Actually charlietfl's solution is much more cleaner and efficient. I have to do the appendTo because of the stupid ASP.NET webform.

Answer (score 2):

Since dialog gets appended to body regardless of where you place the element in your code, and will no longer be a child of your form, just change html to have form as child of dialog

```
<div id="dialog" style="display:none">
   <form method="post" name="change_pass" id="change_pass" action="change_pass2.php">
       <input type="hidden" id="uid" value="<?php echo $userid ?>">    
         <input type="text" name="pass" id="pass">Password :
        <input type="text" name="conf_pass" id="conf_pass">Confirm Password:    
   </form>
</div>
```

The reason for the append to body is to allow positioning to be based on body