# Asp form input field fails to pass the information from jQuery dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, forms

We are trying to make a register form inside a jQuery dialog, but the button which is supposed to transfer the information from the textboxes doesn't send the information - meaning the c# function that I have made, receives blank data. The code that we have is:

This is the button that submits the information(our submit button is outside the jQuery dialog div and it is hidden; we use another js generated button as a shortcut):

```
<asp:Button ID="btntwo" runat="server" style="display:none"  Text="" OnClick="registerSubmit_Click" />
```

This is the code that creates our jQuery dialog (we have javascript function that simulates a click of our asp button):

```
$('#Register').dialog(dialogOpts);
$.fx.speeds._default = 500;
$(function () {
    $("#Register").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        buttons: {
            Ok: function () {
                $("[id*=btntwo]").click();
                $('form').append('#Register');
            }
        },
        show: "blind",
        hide: "explode"
    });
```

This is the code that we use for our input fields, which are located in our jQuery dialog:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="username_textbox" runat="server" />
```

This is our c# function, which takes the data from the input fields and uses this data after that.

```
string username = username_textbox.Text;
```

Here is our problem: the expected result is that the username variable will be whatever is inputted by the user, but instead this variable receives only blank data "".

Comment: when you remove the style="display:none" from your asp button and click it, do you still get the same behavior?

Comment: yes, then the button is just visible, but still doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution for your problem:
[jQuery dialog form submission not POSTing values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11237234/jquery-dialog-form-submission-not-posting-values)

Answer (score 4):

I believe jQuery dialog takes a piece of your HTML, wraps it in dialog container and appends it to body element, meaning your input elements are no longer in your form that’s why they are not transferred… only input elements in form being submitted are sent back to server, other input elements outside the form (including other forms) are not.

Comment: okay, i understand that, but how else can i transfer the information entered in the textboxes?

Comment: well, you could add some code in OK button handler that would take the whole dialog back to the form along with the input element. Simple $('form').append('#dialogID') should do the trick.

Comment: okay, i added it as you say, it is now inside the jQuery dialog but still nothing happens. I have updated the first post so you can see it now.